# Querying from the Controller a List<T> obtained fromt the repository increase coupling?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern, loose-coupling

I have an ASP.NET MVC application coded with C#. The application is structured this way:

1. Controller
2. Repository
3. LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)
4. View

I use the Repository (`_ProductRep`) to query the LINQ to Entities and give to the Controller actual entities or `List<T>`, not `IQueriables<T>`.

I would like to have some help about a situation where I have more than a doubt. I have the following code:

```
List<Monthly_Report> lproduct_monthlyReport = _ProductRep.GetArchiveReport(product.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear);
```

After I get this `lproduct_monthlyReport` I need to query it inside a foreach and get a specific record. Currently I implemented the solution like this:

```
foreach (var item in litemList)
{    
   var lproductItem_monthlyReport = lproduct_monthlyReport.Single(m => m.Item_ID == item.Item_ID);
   // Other code
}
```

Where `litemList` is the list of all the possible items a product can have.

I wanted to know whether this solution sensibly increase the coupling (and violates the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) or it is acceptable because I am actually querying a `List<T>` and not an `IQueriable<T>`. Correct me if I am wrong, but I guess that since the List does not need to access the EF DataContext, there is no coupling between Controller and EF.

In case I am wrong, the only solution I can think about is to substitute the query with a Repository method (that still I have to implement):

```
var lproductItem_monthlyReport_ProductRep.GetArchiveReport(product.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, item.Item_ID);
```

with this solution however the Repository makes one query with 4 conditions every loop cycle whilst in the previous solution the repository was making a query with just one conditions.

May you please enlighten me on this issue? Thanks.

PS: I need both variables `lproduct_monthlyReport` and `lproductItem_monthlyReport` inside the loop, I cannot just use one of them

PPS: I know that I should have a Business Service Layer between Controller and Repository, it is my next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning Lists from your repository will give you awful performance, because you lose the deferred execution behaviour. Basically your repository will retrieve every single record, and not related entities, into memory, and turn them into a List, which then gets processed in memory. If you want to access a related entity, it'll need another database hit. If you stick with IEnumerable (or IQueryable), then you are hiding the nuances of the entity framework behaviour from the client, but still getting the advantages like lazy loading and deferred execution.

Ignoring the specifics of your Repository for now, if you do this:

```
List<Product> products = MyEntities.Products.ToList();

Product product1 = products.Single(p => p.Id = 1);
```

it will perform much worse than this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = MyEntities.Products;

Product product1 = products.Single(p => p.Id = 1);
```

The first one will perform a SELECT in the database with no WHERE clauses, then instantiate .Net objects for every result, then query that in-memory list. The second will do nothing until you access a property on product1 and will at that point issue a database command to just retrieve the 1 product, and only instantiate that 1 product.

The difference between the 2 may not be noticeable with small data sets, but as the data set gets larger this will get worse and worse. Throw in a connected entity (or worse still entity collection), and you'll get potentially thousands of database hits, where if you stuck with IEnumerable you'd get 1.

Comment: I disagree with that. I would recommended returning lists from the DAL. For example calling products.Single(p => p.Id = 1); in the loop without having a list would result in one DB call for every iteration.

Comment: @RichardW1001: Thanks for your answer. The Repository pattern prescribes that only actual entities should be returned by the repository. Then you should be flexible enough to understand where you can relax a specific prescription. However by returning an IQueriable (or IEnumerable) you need the LINQtoSQL context to be open, instead I use the using directive to open the data context (valid just inside the directive area)

Comment: Yes, that would be hideous... but that's the opposite of what I'm saying! I'm saying that if you're going to return a collection of items from your repository, leave it as an IEnumerable  or IQueryable rather than or List, so that you keep deferred execution. The point I'm trying to make is that if you return a List, the database call has already been made, and can only be refined in memory. However if you return IEnumerable, you can add further filters to the query before the database call is made, while keeping the separation and ignorance of EF.

Comment: You cant leave it as IEnumerable or IQueryable if the DataContext is disposed (correctly) in the DAL function. Also I would not recommend sending Linq entities from the DAL, rather use DTO's

Comment: Am I missing something - why the haste to dispose of the context so quickly? You do appreciate that the context and the connection are COMPLETELY separate things? And that creating a new context has a considerable overhead? You shouldn't leave them sitting around, but you should definitely leave them around long enough to correctly retrieve data in the most efficient way! Suggest you fire up a quick console app, and step through the two methods side by side, watching database activity for each one using a trace/profiler - that will explain far better than words can.

Comment: In my opinion the DTO's shouldn't be modified (lazy loading properties) outside the DAL. Also if you return IQuerable/IEnumerable from the DAL functions and someone who uses that function and appends fairly complex lambda expression to it you would never know what the linq expression would evaluate to in SQL, could result in thousands of DB calls.
According to MSDN: "A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create"
and "is designed to last for one 'unit of work'"

Comment: Completely agree... but you're talking about throwing away the context halfway through the unit of work. If the next thing you are going to do is filter your results, your query wasn't finished. My point is that you should delay calling the database until you know what you need from it, whereas if you return Lists, you are retrieving a lot of unnecessary data, and probably not retrieving all the data you do need unless your data structure is trivially simple.

Comment: Another thing... Always ask "WHY" - WHY are you using a repository? Why do you have DTOs? What do you want it do do for you? Does it achieve those goals in the most effective way? The reason I use a variation of the repository pattern is so I can abstract data access against an interface which I can replace easily through IoC, and so I can perform unit testing. I use a very simple generic repository interface, with custom lazy loading using IEnumerable, and it meets those goals beautifully. If whatever you are doing works for you, then great - there's always more than one way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably have function like this `GetArchiveReport(int prodID, int lmonth, int lyear, IEnumerable<int> itemIDs)` that would do a itemIDs.Contains(tbl.ID) inside your query

```
var SelectedReports = _ProductRep.GetArchiveReport(product.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, litemList.Select(item => item.Item_ID));
foreach(var prodItem in SelectedReports)
{
  //Do code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However what is the use of the functions? With the **litemList.Select(item => item.Item_ID)** you actually make a projection. May you please better explain your solution?